# Lamda expression Where VS FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new using `lamda expressions` and i am trying to figure some things.
I have created the following part of code which code returns the file path of a log file.

```
public static string GetLogFile()
{
    var fileTarget = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(t=>t.Name == "LogName") as FileTarget;            
    return fileTarget == null ? string.Empty : fileTarget.FileName.Render(new LogEventInfo { Level = LogLevel.Info });
}
```

My problem is that `fileTarget` is empty when i am using:

```
LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(t=>t.Name == "LogName")
```

But if i change that line of code as

```
LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name == "LogName")
```

Returns the correct path for my log file. Can anyone explain to me if there is a major difference between `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Yeah, `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`. When you try to cast it with `as`, it will return `null`; but `FirstOrDefault` returns an instance that can be casted.

Comment: Where can be read as `Give me all records where name == "LogName"`. FirstOrDefault - `Give me first record where name == "LogName" if there is none - give me null`

Comment: Be careful when using `value as <type>` for casting. If you expect your value to be of that type, then use `(<type>)value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where actually returns an IEnumerable (intellisense will tell you this). It doesnt know how many items your predicate might match. FirstOrDefault will get the first item, or the first item that matches your predicate. If you passed one.

(Nb. A predicate is any function that takes an object and returns a bool, there is a .Net type called `Predicate<T>` that represents it)

To tidy it all up and you could do this, using the OfType linq operator and null propagation and null coalescing  operators

```
public static string GetLogFile()
{
    var fileTarget = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<FileTarget>().FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name == "LogName");            
    return fileTarget?.FileName.Render(new LogEventInfo { Level = LogLevel.Info }) ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `Where` returns a `IEnumerable` (simply a list) of the object `FileTarget`. Then, you cast this list to `FileTarget`. That's why it's null.

But `FirstOrDefault` returns an object or `null` and is castable to your class `FileTarget`. That's why it works.

Comment: "In your case, Where returns a IEnumerable", is there a case where this isn't true? Also, an `IEnumerable` is not a list.

Comment: To be fair to @Camilo, `IEnumerable` also isn't really a list either. It is just a promise that something can be iterated over. For example, you could expose an incoming TCP stream as an `IEnumerable` which certainly isn't a list, and may never end. Minor semantics perhaps, but quite critical.

Comment: @AntoineV I also didn't write `List`, so I don't know what does that comment answer.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words,

`Where` will provide you a Enumerable. Will not be null. Empty if there is no match in the predicate.
`FirstOrDefault` will give you an object. Null if there is no match.

Going by your code, it should throw a compilation error saying it cannot convert from IEnumerable to FileTarget.

Comment: No, it won't throw a compilation error, that's not how `x as y` casting works.